# Track state of order in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Order`.

I want to track 'the life-cycle' of the order, i.e. when and by who it was requested by a customer, when and by who the order was processed, etc.

Right now I just have field determining whether the order is requested, processed, etc. but I don't know how to save additional information about the states.

I guess it's some kind of a kanban system. How could this be obtained? I guess I could make a foreign key to another model `State`/`Status`. Would this work?

Comment: A single Status Field can be enough. If at all you want description, you can  have a `Status Description` field alongside.

Comment: If you plan to implement a `State` (I guess its the state of a single `Order`) you should place the `ForeignKey` on the `State` and not the other way around.

Comment: Also, "would this work?" is a quite vague question and I don't think that you'll get satisfactory responses to it. IMO you should investigate further and precise your question.

Comment: @Constantinius, why do you think so? It is possible to use only several states: New, Pending, Done. In this way an `Order` object will have a `ForeignKey` to a `State`. If any other information about the `State` is required, it should be 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: But if I place the foreign key on the state model, wont it will be possible for an order to have multiple states?

Comment: @Jamgreen, you can use `OneToOneField`.

Comment: But I want to list all the states an order had through its life-cycle, so maybe I need the foreign key to be on state and not the other way around as you say

Comment: a `ForeignKey` on the `Order` model is correct, that means an `Order` can have exactly one `State`... (assuming you even need a `State` model, which I doubt)  a `OneToOneField` means the `State` belongs to the `Order`, i.e. you can only ever have one order that is "Pending" and I don't think that is what you want at all ...and a ForeignKey on the State model is similarly illogical (each State belongs to single order, multiple States can belong to same Order)

Comment: There's a way to store `CurrentState` and `StateHistory`.